# Ankhsvn v2.4 could not be selected for Visual Studio 2013 source control plugin

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2013, ankhsvn

As the company, we were using Ankhsvn v2.3 with VS 2008. Lately, we have upgraded to VS2013 Community Edition, but we do not want to upgrade svn repo version so we upgraded to Ankhsvn v2.4. 
Problem is, everything is okay in VS2012 both for Ankh2.3 and 2.4. However in VS2013, I cannot select it as the source control plugin (Anksvn 2.4) it gives me error saying that i must check the log file in appdata folder.
Any ideas? is this a common issue? I have searched for it but most of the people upgraded their repos so they are using v2.5...

Here is the log file by the way:

```
  <entry>
    <record>876</record>
    <time>2015/05/06 11:22:02.818</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Begin package load [AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio]</description>
    <guid>{604AD610-5CF9-4BD5-8ACC-F49810E2EFD4}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>877</record>
    <time>2015/05/06 11:22:02.818</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio]</description>
    <guid>{604AD610-5CF9-4BD5-8ACC-F49810E2EFD4}</guid>
    <hr>80131602</hr>
    <errorinfo>Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>878</record>
    <time>2015/05/06 11:22:02.818</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [AnkhSVN - Subversion Support for Visual Studio]</description>
    <guid>{604AD610-5CF9-4BD5-8ACC-F49810E2EFD4}</guid>
    <hr>80131602</hr>
    <errorinfo>Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>879</record>
    <time>2015/05/06 11:22:02.818</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Package failed to load; error message suppressed by skip flag</description>
    <guid>{604AD610-5CF9-4BD5-8ACC-F49810E2EFD4}</guid>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>880</record>
    <time>2015/05/06 11:22:02.818</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Construction of frame content failed.&#x000D;&#x000A;Frame identifier: ST:0:0:{c3630016-f162-4af5-b165-9f468a642e9a}&#x000D;&#x000A;Frame caption: &#x000D;&#x000A;Exception details:&#x000D;&#x000A;System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsShell5.LoadPackageWithContext(Guid&amp; packageGuid, Int32 reason, Guid&amp; context)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.GetPackage()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Platform.WindowManagement.WindowFrame.ConstructContent()</description>
  </entry>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was suspecting that VS2013 is an upgraded version of VS2012 (I have both in my local machine), this issue is one of the proofs of it :)

Anyway, I was installing Ankhsvn2.4 only for VS2013. I tried to install it also to VS2012, problem is solved.

Probably, they are using some shared libraries..